# Excel VBA code not compatible in other excel version later than 2016

Tags: vba, excel

I created a simple user forms and it works well with excel version after 2013. But when runs in excel 2010 version, it keep giving me error.

Here is my user form codes

```
Private Sub CloseButton_Click()
Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub ClearButton_Click()
Call UserForm_Initialize
End Sub
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
'Clear Form
'Clear ProjectList
ProjectList.Clear

'Fill ProjectList
With Worksheets("Database")
    ProjectList.List = .Range("Q3:Q" & .Range("Q" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value
End With

'Clear NationalityList
NationalityList.Clear

'Fill NationalityList
With Worksheets("Database")
    NationalityList.List = .Range("H3:H" & .Range("H" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value
End With

'Clear NationalityList
WorkPermitList.Clear

'Fill WorkPermitList
With Worksheets("Database")
    WorkPermitList.List = .Range("J3:J" & .Range("J" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value
End With

'Clear TransferFromList
TransferFromList.Clear

'Fill TransferFromList
With Worksheets("Database")
    TransferFromList.List = .Range("D3:D" & .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value
End With

'Clear TransferToList
TransferToList.Clear

'Fill TransferToList
With Worksheets("Database")
    TransferToList.List = .Range("D3:D" & .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value
End With

'Clear LastPositionList
LastPositionList.Clear

'Fill LastPositionList
With Worksheets("Database")
    LastPositionList.List = .Range("E3:E" & .Range("E" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value
End With

'Clear CurrentPositionList
CurrentPositionList.Clear

'Fill CurrentPositionList
With Worksheets("Database")
    CurrentPositionList.List = .Range("F3:F" & .Range("F" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value
End With

'Clear Certificates
cert1list.Clear
cert2list.Clear
cert3list.Clear
cert4list.Clear
cert5list.Clear
cert6list.Clear
cert7list.Clear

'Fill CurrentPositionList
With Worksheets("Database")
    cert1list.List = .Range("R3:R" & .Range("R" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value
    cert2list.List = .Range("R3:R" & .Range("R" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value
    cert3list.List = .Range("R3:R" & .Range("R" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value
    cert4list.List = .Range("R3:R" & .Range("R" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value
    cert5list.List = .Range("R3:R" & .Range("R" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value
    cert6list.List = .Range("R3:R" & .Range("R" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value
    cert7list.List = .Range("R3:R" & .Range("R" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value
End With

'Clear Action List
NameText.Value = " "
ContactNumber.Value = " "
Age.Value = " "
DOB.Value = " "
NRIC.Value = " "
ECSOC.Value = " "
DDJV.Value = " "

'Uncheck DataCheckBoxes
CheckBox1.Value = False
CheckBox2.Value = False

End Sub
Private Sub SubmitButton_Click()
Dim emptyRow As Long

'Make Sheet1 active
Sheet3.Activate

ActiveSheet.Unprotect "eastmarine123"

'Determine emptyRow
emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("c:c")) + 1

'Crew Transfer information
Cells(emptyRow, 5).Value = ProjectList.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 6).Value = NameText.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 7).Value = ContactNumber.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 8).Value = Age.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 9).Value = DOB.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 10).Value = ECSOC.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 11).Value = DDJV.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 12).Value = NationalityList.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 13).Value = WorkPermitList.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 14).Value = TransferFromList.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 15).Value = TransferToList.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 16).Value = NRIC.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 17).Value = LastPositionList.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 18).Value = CurrentPositionList.Value

'OptionBox & CheckBox
If OptionButton1.Value = True Then Cells(emptyRow, 19).Value = OptionButton1.Caption
If OptionButton2.Value = True Then Cells(emptyRow, 20).Value = OptionButton2.Caption
If CheckBox1.Value = True Then Cells(emptyRow, 21).Value = CheckBox1.Caption
If CheckBox2.Value = True Then Cells(emptyRow, 22).Value = CheckBox2.Caption

'Certificate List
Cells(emptyRow, 23).Value = cert1list.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 24).Value = cert2list.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 25).Value = cert3list.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 26).Value = cert4list.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 27).Value = cert5list.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 28).Value = cert6list.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 29).Value = cert7list.Value

'Register current date and time
Cells(emptyRow, 3).Value = Date
Cells(emptyRow, 4).Value = Time

ActiveSheet.Protect "eastmarine123", True, True
ThisWorkbook.Save

End Sub
```

When I run the debug, it gives the the error on these two "Date"and "Time"

```
Cells(emptyRow, 3).Value = Date
Cells(emptyRow, 4).Value = Time
```

When I delete these two rows , it then runs fine. I thought the Date and Time function suppose to be compatible throughout the office version?

Comment: what's the error message?

Comment: Try changing `Time` to `Time()`

Comment: You may be missing a reference to `VBA` library. Seems odd, but that would cause the problem you're describing.

Comment: Does `VBA.DateTime.Time` and `VBA.DateTime.Date` give the same errors.

Comment: Thank you guys for your precious comments. I've went along @DavidZemens suggestion that reference might be missing. So what I did is clearing the check box for the type library or object library marked as "Missing:" in the VBA editor and it does the tricks!